# sqlcmd export the query to csv in utf8

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, utf-8, sqlcmd

i would like to export my query result to csv file in utf-8.

Now i export to csv with sqlcmd

My SQL File:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test.dbo.T_LIF;
```

My Windows Batch File

```
@echo off

sqlcmd -S MyServer\SQLServer2008 -E -s; -W -i t_lif_export.sql | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > t_lif_export.csv
```

Incorrect Output:
*Sanit„r- und Heizungsgroáhandel*

Correct Output:
*Sanitär- und Heizungsgroßhandel*

How do I get the correct output in utf-8?

Comment: Problem solved: Add `chcp 1252` to the bat file

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me a file that looked clean in ANSI, but shows characters in UTF-8.  They needed a row updated, to remove a UTF-8 character.  Posted below is what I used to get SQLCMD to work, since -f 65001 did not.  I believe query output would be in UTF-8 as well.

```
sqlcmd -s serverName -f i:1252 -i c:\sqlUpdate.sql -f o:65001 -o c:\sqlUpdateOutput.sql -d userDatabaseName
```